# Can't save matplotlib animation

Tags: python, animation, matplotlib, ffmpeg, save

I am trying to get a simple animation saved using ffmpeg. I followed a tutorial to install ffmpeg, and I can now access it from the command prompt.

Now I run this piece of code:

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import animation

fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.axes(xlim=(0, 2), ylim=(-2, 2))
line, = ax.plot([], [], lw=2)

def init():
    line.set_data([], [])
    return line,

def animate(i):
    x = np.linspace(0, 2, 1000)
    y = np.sin(2 * np.pi * (x - 0.01 * i))
    line.set_data(x, y)
    return line,

anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, init_func=init,
                               frames=200, interval=20, blit=True)

mywriter = animation.FFMpegWriter()
anim.save('mymovie.mp4',writer=mywriter)

plt.show()
```

I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\spyderlib\widgets\externalshell\sitecustomize.py", line 523, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)
  File "C:\Users\Renger\.xy\startups\b.py", line 23, in <module>
    anim.save('mymovie.mp4',writer=mywriter)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\animation.py", line 609, in save
    with writer.saving(self._fig, filename, dpi):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\contextlib.py", line 17, in __enter__
    return self.gen.next()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\animation.py", line 166, in saving
    self.setup(*args)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\animation.py", line 156, in setup
    self._run()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\animation.py", line 183, in _run
    stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\subprocess.py", line 711, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\subprocess.py", line 948, in _execute_child
    startupinfo)
WindowsError: [Error 2] Het systeem kan het opgegeven bestand niet vinden
```

The last dutch sentence does mean something like: The system can't find the specified file.

What do these errors mean, and how can I solve them?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You need to specify your path to `ffmpeg`:

On linux I use:

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import animation
plt.rcParams['animation.ffmpeg_path'] = '/usr/bin/ffmpeg'
```

You will obviously have to point to your windows .exe instead of '/usr/bin/ffmpeg'

If you don't have `ffmpeg` installed, you can get it [here](http://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/builds/)

Comment: At first it still didn't work this way, but it turns out I had to use a double slash everywhere. Don't know why.

Comment: using  / slash or raw string will work  r'C:...' \  escapes characters in python.

Comment: I had to set the `rcParam` before importing `matplotlib.animation`. May be related to changes in Matplotlib (`__version__ == '1.5.2'`) or to peculiarities of my Windows installation.

Comment: Or your can add the path of the ffmpeg executable to your PATH variable.

Comment: I had this problem using Anaconda. I ran `which ffmpeg` and saw that it was using Anaconda's ffmpeg.

Answer (score 7):

for some animation "anim" i use on windows:

```
plt.rcParams['animation.ffmpeg_path'] ='E:\\Media\\ffmpeg\\bin\\ffmpeg.exe'
FFwriter = animation.FFMpegWriter()
anim.save('basic_animation.mp4', writer = FFwriter, fps=30)
```

where path should be with \ \ and not with / or \ between folders

Comment: Code-only answers are auto-flagged as low quality and as such are discouraged on stackoverflow. In the future please embellish your answer with details and explain why it is a solution to the question.

Comment: This works but I had to pass the `fps = 100` argument in `FFMpegWriter()` constructor: `FFwriter = animation.FFMpegWriter(fps = 100)`.

Answer (score 0):

Line 183 in animation.py is the `subprocess.Popen` call to `ffmpeg`. It seems that the `ffmpeg` exe is not where matplotlib expects it to be.

My first attempt would be to put the install path (directory) to `ffmpeg`  into the windows `Path` environmental variable.  I'm guessing that animation.py is expecting it to be available globally (as it would be under Linux).

If that doesn't work, I'd inspect the `subprocess.Popen` call in animation.py to see exactly what it is doing.  You could break point it or adjust the verbose.report variable in your [matplotlibrc](http://matplotlib.org/1.3.1/users/customizing.html) file to spit it out.  Line 179 there is:

```
verbose.report('MovieWriter.run: running command: %s' %
                   ' '.join(command))
```

Comment: I am printing verbose.report, but it just says "False". How do I get more details?

Answer (score 0):

On Windows, I had to use 
`plt.rcParams['animation.ffmpeg_path'] = 'C:\\mypath'` with all double '\' in the path and this line has to be mentioned before

```
from matplotlib import animation
```

and mypath = path of ffmpeg.exe on the local disk.

Additionally, I also added the ffmpeg path in the environment variables.

It took me two days and after going through tons of advice I was able to solve this issue of saving animation.

Thank you everyone for all the answers.